# To render contents for a website frontend from django backend

Tags: django, database

Im going to build a website in angular and I need to render the contents from the backend on MySQL
I need help for designing a data model for the website

How to plan the data model for content management for a website from the backend. I need a clear explanation for database structure.

Comment: This is a Q&A platform. Ask specific programing questions. Someone can't know the design in your mind and design it for you. Thanks.